# Why is font-stretch:condensed an invalid property value in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I am trying to use `font-stretch:condensed` and it shows as invalid in Google Chrome Developer tools when inspecting it.

[image]

It renders fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no support to `font-stretch` in Chrome yet.

The Developer tools misrepresent the situation: it is the *property* `font-stretch` that is “invalid” to Chrome, i.e. not supported by Chrome, not just the particular value `condensed`. However, Chrome recognizes the name; if you declare `foo: bar`, then the tools tell that `foo` is an unknown property name.

As a workaround, declare the condensed typeface you wish to use as the value of `font-family`, i.e. as if it were a font family and not just a particular typeface in a family. For example, instead of

```
font-family: Bodoni MT;
font-stretch: condensed;
```

(which works in IE 10, but not in Chrome or Firefox, although the latter claims to support `font-stretch`) you would write

```
font-family: Bodoni MT Condensed;
```

The specific name of the typeface must be either its PostScript name or its full name, as given in the names table in the font file corresponding to `nameID` values 4 and 6. You can find out this data using [DTL OTMaster Light](http://www.fontmaster.nl/english/downloads.html).

Note that using a specific typeface is the same thing that `font-stretch` does by definition, see [CSS Fonts Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/) LC. The name `font-stretch` is a misnomer; the property does not stretch a font – it only selects a typeface with the given width when such a typeface exists.

Comment: That's one of those weird quirks with Chrome where property appears to be valid, even though it hasn't been implemented.  I think `transform` (instead of `-webkit-transform`) will do this sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Almost ten years later, it looks like Chrome still does not fully support `font-stretch` - even though it should be possible to use it in presence of a `@font-face` declaration, as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-stretch. However, I am successfully using the approach suggested in rookie1024's comment, namely using the following simple CSS class:

```
.condensed-text {
  transform: scaleX(0.7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `font-stretch` property isn't part of any final standard and Chrome doesn't support it. See [font-stretch on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-stretch#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: As per 2023, it's now valid.